# Mailchimp API on Laravel, How do I use it in a route?

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp

I am new to Laravel and am stuck. I've use the [Hugo Firth](https://github.com/hugofirth/laravel-mailchimp) api wrapper in Laravel for mailchimp. What I can't figure out is where to put this the code in laravel. Does it go on the controller? This is the code for subscribe:

```
MailChimpWrapper::lists()->subscribe($list_id, array('email' => $email_address));
```

I know how to make a form inline in php and html, but I want to be able to use the mailchimp API through the route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in a controller, for example:

```
class SubscribeerController extends BaseController {

    public function emailSubscribe($list_id)
    {
        $email_address = Input::get('email_address'); // from the form input
        MailChimpWrapper::lists()
                        ->subscribe($list_id, array('email' => $email_address));
    }

}
```

Then use this to declare a route:

```
Route::post('subscribe/{list_id}', 'SubscribeerController@emailSubscribe');
```

Then the `URI` could be something like this:

```
// 10 assumed the list_id for example
http://domain.com/subscribe/10
```

if you want to send the `$list_id` using a form field then you don't need to use `{list_id}` in the route and also don't need to pass it with the `URI`, instead you may retrieve it using:

```
Input::get('list_id'); // Assumed list_id is the form's input name
```

In this case `emailSubscribe($list_id)` should be `emailSubscribe()` as well (When not using `{list_id}` in `route` and `URI` is `http://domain.com/subscribe`).

Comment: Will this work on an inline form? I have a form on my landing page for people to subscribe with.

Comment: I am very new to all this. I will try it out. Thank you.

Comment: I tried it out but can't figure out how to get my form to talk to my API.  When a user submits their email I just want it to say thank you and send the email via api.  I don't want them to have to go to a new page or antyhing.  Maybe using routes isn't right?